# Network Traffic Spiking

Tags: networking, ethernet, asus, nic

I have recently installed an 10 GBit NIC from Asus, the XG-C100C 10 GBit Network Card, which is connected to a Switch using a 5GBit Link.

I am using an AMD Threadripper 1950x with an X399 Aorus Gaming 7 Motherboard by Gigabyte.

I have installed the latest Kernel Module (v1.65) for the AQN-107 Chip inside the Network Card by Aquaris.

Here is an image of how it looks like when I try to measure network traffic using iperf:

[image]

I am getting roughly 2.2 GBit throughput using iperf between my machine and a server machine. 2 Servers connected with 5 GBit each managed to transfer at 4.7 GBit/s, so there is nothing wrong with my switch/network configuration.

Has anyone got an idea how to fix this?

When using the Internal 1 Gigabit NIC everything seems fine.